# Exit early from the pipeline if there are no arguments to xargs

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe, xargs

Say I have this pipeline:

```
pgrep -P $$ | xargs kill -INT; sleep 0.6; pgrep -P $$ | xargs kill -9;
```

What I want to do is avoid the sleep call if there are no arguments to xargs.

Something like this:

```
pgrep -P $$ | (exit if no args) | xargs kill -INT; sleep 0.6; pgrep -P $$ | xargs kill -9;
```

How can I do this cleanly? I don't want to mess up the pipeline and get weird errors.

Comment: Whatever is there would have to wait until pgrep exits and has no more stdout I guess.

Comment: `pgrep -P $$ | xargs kill -INT && sleep 0.6; pgrep -P $$ | xargs kill -9`?

Comment: hmmm, so xargs exits with 1 if there are no arguments? the problem is what if exits with 1 for other reasons?

Comment: `kill` exits `1` if it receives no args, not `xargs`. That said, in your current command, if kill or xargs blows up, then: you'll probably get a message on standard error, sleep will run, and the second pgrep | xargs combo will run. Same scenario as I describe here, just without the sleep. If you want to only run the second pgrep | xargs combo if the first succeeds, then you'd want: `pgrep -P $$ | xargs kill -INT && { sleep 0.6; pgrep -P $$ | xargs kill -9; }`

Comment: Hi  Alexander. I'm one of the volunteer editors here, and one of the things we try to do is to edit posts so they are as readable as possible. We fix punctuation, case, spelling, formatting etc, and trim chat and wordiness - in short, we aim for quality technical writing, at least in theory. With that in mind, I wonder if you could try aiming for the same? It'd save us some work if, for example, we did not need to trim "lol" txtspk from your posts - that's fine for Facebook, but not here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

GNU `xargs` has the `-r` option specifically for this use case.  You'll have to refactor the script slightly; I would simply go with

```
pgrep -P $$ | xargs -r kill -INT
( sleep 0.6; pgrep -P $$ | xargs -r kill 9 ) &
```

The second command will simply end up being a no-op if the first manages to kill all the subprocesses.

This is not portable to *BSD etc where `xargs` lacks this option.

Comment: upvoted, but cannot select, because it needs to work on BSD too

Answer (score 1):

The amount of data being processed here (a list of PIDs) is tiny, so you don't need pipes and 'xargs'.  Try:

```
if childpids=$(pgrep -P $$) ; then
    kill -INT $childpids
    sleep 0.6
    childpids=$(pgrep -P $$) && kill -9 $childpids
fi
```

[ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) complains about missing quotes on `$childpids`, but it is harmless to omit them in this case, and it would be wrong to add them.